# free( ) leads to malloc_error_break

Tags: c, network-programming, malloc, free, sigabrt

```
void close_TCP_connection(TCP_Connection *tcp)
{
  if (tcp)
  {
    printf(" CHIUSURA %s\n", tcp->sendbuf);
    if (tcp->sockfd)
    {
      socketDestroy(tcp->sockfd);
    }

    if (tcp->recvbuf)
    {
      free(tcp->recvbuf);
    } //fi

    if (tcp->sendbuf)
    {
      printf(" CHIUSURA 2%s\n", tcp->sendbuf);
      free(tcp->sendbuf);
    } //fi

    if (tcp->addr)
    {
      free(tcp->addr);
    } //fi
  } //fi
}
```

I have this function inserted in a very great project. This function has goal to release all the members of a structure TCP_connection. This structure contains all info about a connection client-server.

When I launch the program, I observe an error in `free(tcp->sendbuf);` , the `printf` over this line works correctly. The error that I have when I debug  the code  is :

```
215             free(tcp->sendbuf);
(gdb) 
charms_client(49045) malloc: *** error for object 0x10006ec80: pointer being freed was       
not allocated
 *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

 Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
 0x00007fff8ccddd46 in __kill ()enter code here
```

I allocate the structure in another function

```
int init_TCPConnection(TCP_Connection *tcp, char *servername, int server_port, int client_port)
{
  tcp->sendbuf = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_BUF_LEN);
  tcp->sendlen = (size_t)MAX_BUF_LEN;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: you can call free for an address that is returned from malloc/calloc function.

Comment: Show us how you allocate the memory that `tcp->sendbuf` references!

Comment: You have an answer of you issue in the debug message : `pointer being freed was not allocated`. Probably you try to `free` memory bytes which haven't been allocated using `malloc` family function. I guess `tcp->sendbuf` points to memory area on the stack, or to memory area previously released.

Comment: I haven't released the pointer. But according to you @sgnsajgon can this operation "atoi(tcp->sendbuf) == ERROR" create this kind of problem? I say this because, if I remove this operation there isn't this problem.... :(

Comment: As there seems to be an issue with memory it might be a good idea to run the program under a memory checker like Valgrind: http://valgrind.org

Comment: You can perform a trial: attach a debugger to process, set a breakpoint and get a value of the pointer after `malloc()` invocation. Then set a second breakpoint and get the second value of the pointer, just before invocation of `free()`. Compare pointer values. If they are the same, you likely `free()` the buffer twice. If they differs, the pointer is re-assigned and changed somewhere is the code. The third option is that your struct is not created with memory dynamic allocation (by `init_TCPConnection` function), but is stored on the stack as local variable with uninitialized members.

Answer (score 1):

You propably `free()` the buffer twice.

To avoid this mark the `free()`ed pointer as such by assigning `NULL` it after having `free()`ed the memory it pointed to.

```
free(tcp->sendbuf);
tcp->sendbuf = NULL;
```

Any subsequend calls to `free()` using this pointer will result in doing nothing as passing `NULL` to `free()` is harmless.

It is good practise to do so for any pointer having been passed to `free()`.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement @alk ... The free() works correctly until I begin to do operation over tcp->sendbuf such as  "atoi(tcp->sendbuf) == ERROR"...

Comment: @EngAndreaR: "*... The free() works correctly ...*": In your question you mention: "*... I observe an error in free(tcp->sendbuf); ...*" So what, please?

Comment: Sorry. In this project this function "close_TCP_connection" works correctly until I begin to do some operation over "tcp->sendbuf". This operation is an "if(atoi(tcp->sendbuf) == -1)". I ask you, if according to you, this operation can create problem to "free()" operation

Comment: No, `atoi()` does not modify what is being passed in. Btw: `atoi()` does not return `-1` on error, but `0`. However, please see my comment on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You are either freeing the send buffer twice or else you are corrupting its value, e.g. via `tcp->sendbuffer++`.

NB You don't need to test all those pointers before freeing them. `free()` already does that. You are just doubling the work.